# How to get Course modules details in moodle's default Web service

Tags: ios, module, default, moodle

I am working with moodle, and I want to use moodle's default web service.

With a user with required parameters, all services are working fine.

But it doesn’t work properly for mobile application trying to get Course module details.

I get course title detail through `core_course_get_contents` default web service but not getting details of any course modules (wiki,lesson,quiz,..).

I'm referring to the documentation at [Web services Roadmap](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services_Roadmap), but I am unable to get much information.

Comment: you will need to get some more details to get some answer from the community. Are there any errors?? or some code you have written.,

Comment: Yes, i had used rest client to test serivce, but no other default web service is allow me to get in details, as lesson description and other, i want to use default service as moodle provide, do you have any idea how to get details , which web service is useful for that

Comment: Any idea which default service is useful to get course module details